# Using a query as a parameter in a scalar function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using a scalar function that has already been created for general use. I was trying to use a query for the value of the parameter. But it is not working.

1. I tried to define the parameter at the beginning like `@data1 = select max(return_date) from My_table`
2. I tried calling the query within the function like `select * from my_function(select max(return_date) from My_table)`.

```sql
--- Need the max date from #test table to plugin My_function
create table #test 
(
    id float
    ,return_date date    
);

insert into #test (id, return_date) values(1,'1/31/2019')
insert into #test (id, return_date) values(2,'2/28/2019')
insert into #test (id, return_date) values(3,'3/31/2019')
insert into #test (id, return_date) values(4,'4/30/2019')
insert into #test (id, return_date) values(5,'5/31/2019')
insert into #test (id, return_date) values(6,'5/31/2019')
insert into #test (id, return_date) values(7,'5/31/2019')
insert into #test (id, return_date) values(8,'4/30/2019')
```

I need everything from my function which has one date parameter `@date1`. But `@date1` should take the max date from `#test`. In this case `5/31/2019`.

I am getting an incorrect syntax error for both attempts.

Comment: You started your question well with some DDL and data but the actual question part of your question does not use that ddl at all. Create an [mcve] where any user could copy/paste the content of the code into SSMS and run it and experience the error or output that you get.

Comment: As said above, please show your actual code used in your 2 attempts.

Comment: Need you to post your error as well.

Comment: "Getting an incorrect syntax error for both attempts".  Where're the attempts???

Answer (score 1):

Both of your attempts should work in principle. However you have a few mistakes that need to be corrected:

1. For a scalar function you need to select the function itself, not *from* the function. You only select from table valued functions.
2. To reference a function in SQL Server you must qualify it with the schema name e.g. `dbo.my_function`
3. To embed a query as a function parameter you need additional brackets around the query.

Option 1 - Obtain the value into a variable

```
declare @data1 date;
select @data1 = max(return_date) from #test;

select dbo.my_function(@data1);
```

Option 2 - call the function with an embedded query

```
select dbo.my_function((select max(return_date) from #test));
```